# The token is undefined after the nuxt.js route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Using js-cookie after the parameter is routed, the token in the cookie becomes undefined in the background debug and the token parsing fails.

`<router-link :to="'/qa/item/'+item.id" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</router-link>`

This is my request tool class

```
import axios from 'axios'
    import {getUser} from '@/utils/auth'
    // create
    const service = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9012',
    // base_url
        timeout: 30000, // time
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ getUser().token  }
      })
    export default service
```

This is my auth tool class

```
 import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
    const TokenKey = 'User-Token'
    const NameKey = 'User-Name'
    const AvatarKey = 'User-Avatar'
    export function setUser(token,name,avatar) { 
        Cookies.set(NameKey, name)
        Cookies.set(AvatarKey, avatar)
        Cookies.set(TokenKey, token)
      }
      export function getUser() {
      return {
        token:Cookies.get(TokenKey),
        name:Cookies.get(NameKey),
        avatar:Cookies.get(AvatarKey)
      }
    }
    export function removeUser() {
      Cookies.remove(TokenKey)
      Cookies.remove(NameKey)
      Cookies.remove(AvatarKey)
    }
```

This is the request method when the page is loaded.

```
findById(id) {
    return request({
        url: `/${group_name}/${api_name}/${id}`,
        method: 'get'
    })
},
```

The request tokens sent by other pages and this page are not undefined. When the click of this dynamic routing page is loaded, the tokens are invalid.

Comment: Can you check the browser dev-tools if the cookie gets set correctly and has the token data, before you route? Also can you check, what happens to the cookie, when you route?

Comment: Check the cookie before routing, there is no problem with the token but the token carried by the page after the route is invalid.

Comment: What does the cookie say, after your routing? Is the cookie data identical? Is the token identical?

Comment: I debug the other in the background undefined